# jquery load() after a h4 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get jqery's load to load sometime after a particular tag? In my case, I'll be loading a form after the h4 tag. That's where it needs to go. My problem is: the H4 tag will disappear. Is there anyway to get the form to load under the H4 tag?

jquery:

```
$("#loadForm").click(function() {
    $("#entry").load("load.forms.php?option=" + $("#loadForm").val());
});
```

markup:

```
<div id="post">
    <div id="entry">
        <h4>My Heading</h4>
        //The Form goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @iX3 My bad. It's an H4. But the same thing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use InsertAfter

http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

Then you can select out the h3 tag and insert after it

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra element under the heading, and load the data in there?

```
$("#loadForm").click(function() {
    $("#entry div.form").load("load.forms.php?option=" + $("#loadForm").val());
});

<div id="post">
    <div id="entry">
        <h4>My Heading</h4>
        <div class="form"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```